# Customising Tweets

Tags: twitter

I have some PHP creating automatic Twitter updates, which in the small print at the bottom reads "[date/n minutes ago] via API".

Is it possible to somehow change the "via API" part to something more useful and descriptive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have to utilize OAuth authentication.  As per [the Twitter API Wiki](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/FAQ):

> **How do I get “from [MyApp]” appended to updates sent from my API application?**
>
> We now recommend developers use OAuth to perform authentication with the API. When applications use OAuth, Twitter automatically knows the source of status updates. We are therefore able to append source attribution (from "[MyApp]") to tweets. If you would like tweets from your application to recieve a source parameter, please register an application and implement OAuth authentication. We will automatically include your application as the source for any tweets sent from your application.
>
> We originally allowed applications to create a source paramter for non-OAuth use but that has been discontinued. Applications pre-OAuth source parameters will remain active, but new registrations are no longer accepted.

Comment: Also Basic authentication will stop working at the end of June so you need to use oAuth (or xAuth) or you application will stop working as well.